# Is there a WYSIWYG text editor that can be used for both React Native and Web Browsers (Javascript)?

Tags: react-native, cross-platform, wysiwyg, text-editor

I am looking for a text editor (WYSIWYG) that can be implemented in both a web browser and a react native app to support a cross-platform application.

This means that someone can edit the text in the app, and it will edit the rendering in the web, and vice versa.

Thank you

Comment: I was trying to find something like that for a good while and didn't find anything good.

Answer (score 0):

Try the react-native-cn-richtext-editor
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cn-richtext-editor

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for React Native Web, as it requires a WebView.